# Frog jumps across a river with stones

Tags: algorithm

This is *different* from the classic codility Frog-River-One with leaves falling at different times problem.

[Problem statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjPR2.png)

There is a part where it got cut off: If the monkey can just jump across river, the function returns 0. If it's impossible to jump across river, then -1.

Some test cases include:

[[-1, 5, -1, 5, -1, 10], 3] -> returns 5

[[1, -1, 0, 2, 3, 5], 3] -> returns 2

[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 3] -> returns 0

The image has a problem description. I did this in a brute-force way using recursion, and although I believe it returned correct answers, it probably wasn't good enough because it would yield run time of O(n^D).

Is there a way to solve this problem more efficiently? What am I not seeing? I feel that there might be a DP solution or like a simple math trick... I am attaching my solution for reference.

[My recursive solution with explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOPVH.png)

Comment: You post a _picture_ of _code_???

Comment: Sorry, it was a codility problem and I couldn't copy and paste the code...

Answer (score 3):

Note that the earliest time you can reach `x = i` can be expressed by the following recurrence relation:

```
shortest[i] = if A[i] = -1 then +inf 
              else max(A[i], min{shortest[j] | i - D <= j < i})
```

So first there is a simple `O(ND)` solution using only dynamic programming.

This can actually be reduced to `O(N + D)` using an efficient algorithm to maintain the mininum of `shortest` on the sliding window `[i-D ... i]` (using double-ended queue).